# std::move into static_pointer_cast: Why doesn't static_pointer_cast have an rvalue reference overload?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a fuction expecting a shared pointer by value. (In a real life example I take it by rvalue reference and forward it to a member.)

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr) { ... }
```

But we only have a shared pointer to the base class, so we use `static_pointer_cast`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
f(std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(ptr));
```

Does the first assignment (construction of ptr from the temporary) trigger an atomic increment and decrement of the reference count or is the shared pointer moved? (Note that it's being up-casted.)

Within the `static_pointer_cast` there is an atomic increment of the reference count. In case we don't need `ptr` anymore, we'd want to move it into `f`. But as there is no overload of `static_pointer_cast` taking an rvalue reference, the move won't have any effect:

```
f(std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(std::move(ptr)));
```

We still have the atomic increment and the corresponding atomic decrement as soon as `ptr` is destructed. Why is there no such overload?

Comment: speculation: the "possible implementations" listed here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast all use a constructor for `shared_ptr` that does not accept a moved parameter. Now why *that* doesn't have a move variation I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Can't you move the result of static_pointer_cast?

Comment: @rubenvb the result of static_pointer_cast is a temporary and thus an rvalue, so it's moved automatically. But the problem is that you apparently can't move into static_pointer_cast.

Comment: How about using the converting "move constructor" of shared_ptr? Number 10 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: @rubenvb Doesn't work, that only works if the pointer converts implicitly, i.e. upcast not down.

Comment: Ah yes. Indeed. I forgot this between reading your question, my first comment, and writing my second comment. It does seem C++17 alleviates that by specifying "compatible pointer types", or is that really no better? Can't seem to find a definition of that right now.

Comment: @rubenvb It seems like that could work with C++17.

Comment: @Creep4Play Reference? There is no way to determine that a base class pointer can be safely converted into a derived pointer without a dynamic cast. Dynamic cast risks a runtime error which is not permitted for the heterogeneous move constructor (it is `noexcept` and has to successfully construct).

Comment: @NirFriedman Same reference: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). I don't know the C++17 draft, so I don't know if in case of a downcast, it would do an (unsafe) static cast or a (safe) dynamic cast. The latter is not impossible at all, because: A dynamic cast does not trigger a runtime error. It will return a null pointer instead. There is nothing wrong with move constructing an empty `shared_ptr`. Still it would be better to have move versions of static_pointer_cast and dynamic_pointer_cast imo, cause then one could chose between safe and unsafe.

Comment: @Creep4Play The link explicitly says that after construction `*this` contains the previous state of the argument. That means it cannot be null unless the argument is null. Constructors in C++ are not supposed to fail that way because then their post conditions would be invalidated. E.g.: `auto a = b; auto c = std::move(b); assert(a == c)` should always work for all regular types if an exception is not thrown.

Comment: @Creep4Play You still haven't given any reference that actually shows that it would work with C++17... I don't think it would, I don't think that's what compatible means in this context, and that's why I asked you for a link to clarify why you think it would work in 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  can answer the first part of your question, but not the second. While I'm not sure whether it's mandated by the standard, I'm pretty sure that:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

Will not do any extraneous refcounter increments/decrements. First, let me observe that this is actually not an assignment at all, but construction of `ptr`. Clearly it's been constructed by a temporary, and clearly the temporary is of a different type. The signature of the constructor that will be matched is (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y>&& r );
```

In the notes it says:

> Move-constructs a shared_ptr from r. After the construction, *this contains a copy of the previous state of r, r is empty and its stored pointer is null. The template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is not implicitly convertible to T*

In this case, `Y` is `Derived` and `T` is `Base`, so clearly we get implicit conversion from `Y*` to `T*`, so the constructor is legal. Strictly speaking it might be conforming to allow the reference count to first rise to 2, and then drop back down to 1. But obviously this defeats the whole purpose of a move constructor so I rather strongly doubt this is how it is implemented.